# Read folder content and finds lastwritetime of today if finds file which was lastwritetime of today email it

Tags: powershell

I have a folder which a log is written to it any time a job fails, the folder contains all older logs as well. The goal is to send an email to user on daily basis with the log file generated. If the log found, sends the file in attachment, else sends an email stating file not found. I put below script but the problem is that it reads all files, even though there is only one log file for today.

```
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$LogPath    = "C:\Temp\Error"
$filename   = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\Error" 
foreach ($file in $LogPath) {
  $fileDate = ($file.LastWriteTime).DayOfYear

  if ($fileDate -eq $TodaysDate) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
  }
}
$LogFile       = $LogPath + $filename
$LogFileName   = $LogFile | ? {Test-Path $LogFile} | Get-ChildItem |
                   Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }
$MessageBodyNA = "Email from task scheduler. No log file found" + $filename
$MessageBodyA  = "Email from task scheduler. File" + $LogFileName + 
                 " found and attached"
#
$FromAddress   = "test@gmail.com"
#
$ToAddress     = "test@gmail.com"
$Subject       = "Bad log"
# SMTP server name
$SMTPserver    = "smtp.test"
# check if attachment file exists if so email with attachment else without
# attachment
if ( $LogFileName | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }) {
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject `
    -body $MessageBodyA -smtpServer $SMTPserver -Attachments $LogFileName
} else {
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject `
    -body $MessageBodyNA  -smtpServer $SMTPserver
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routine to determine the file is totally convoluted. Change this:

```
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$LogPath    = "C:\Temp\Error"
$filename   = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\Error" 
foreach ($file in $LogPath) {
  $fileDate = ($file.LastWriteTime).DayOfYear

  if ($fileDate -eq $TodaysDate) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
  }
}
$LogFile       = $LogPath + $filename
$LogFileName   = $LogFile | ? {Test-Path $LogFile} | Get-ChildItem |
                   Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }
```

into this:

```
$LogPath     = "C:\Temp\Error"
$LogFileName = Get-ChildItem $LogPath | ? {
                 -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
                 $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date
               }
```